# Progress bar is jumping

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

When I start program, I need to load some projects and init them. So I make that all in Thread and create a progress bar (next PB). When loading is started everythink is OK, but in one moment PB is stop and jump to end when init will end.

[image: Progress bar]

Here Thread which add to progress bar every init bLock.

```
public void initMapBlocks(int n, int m)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate ()
        {
            Loader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate ()
                {
                    MapPart mp = new MapPart();
                    mainCanvas.Children.Add(mp);
                    Loader.addPoint(1);
                });
            }
        }
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate ()
        {
            Loader.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });

    }
```

Did it`s possible to get full animation?

**-------- Update --------**
Here code where i add to progress bar value.

```
public void addPoint(int x)
    {
        itemCountAlready += x;
        loaderBar.Value += x;
    }
```

**----- Update 2 -------**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => initMapBlocks(100, 100)));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the Value of the ProgressBar? What is your code snippet supposed to do?

Comment: @mm8 function addPoint which I include in Update. loaderBar it`s progress bar.

Comment: All the code you have posted runs on the UI thread. Where is your long-running work?

Comment: @mm8 I wrote in description that initBlocks work on another Thread. In Update 2 You have it.

Comment: But all the code in the initBlocks method, excepts for the actual iteration, is executed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `initMapBlocks` method produces (MapPart) and consumes (adds loader's value and mainCanvas children)  at the same time. You can separate by using `System.Collections.Generic.Queue`

You can define your queue like this

```
private Queue<MapPart> myQueue = new Queue<MapPart>();
```

Instead of these guys

```
mainCanvas.Children.Add(mp);
Loader.addPoint(1);
```

You can write simply this for produce

```
myQueue.Enqueue(mp);
```

And you can define a DispatcherTimer in your constructor for consume

```
DispatcherTimer myTimer = new DispatcherTimer {
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
};
myTimer.Tick += Consume;
myTimer.Start();
```

Your `Consume` method

```
private void Consume(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if (myQueue.Count > 0) {
        //you don't need `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate...` too
        loaderBar.Value += myQueue.Dequeue();
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(mp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DispatcherTimer myTimer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
            };
            myTimer.Tick += Consume;
            myTimer.Start();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => initMapBlocks(100, 100)));
            thread.Start();` Consume will work after end of thread ;\

Comment: Ok , i find a problem :)